# Deleting objects with django framework or javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a page that has a simple form. When I submit this form I am redirected to the same page with the new objects created. I'd like to add inline links to the right of every object created to delete and edit. Would I do this with django or would I use javascript/AJAX to handle this? I'm just a little confused on the approach that I should take. Any suggestions?

Here's what my view currently looks like:

```
def events(request):
    the_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    event_list = Event.objects.filter(user=the_user)
    if request.POST:
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = EventForm(initial={'user':the_user})
    return render_to_response("events/event_list.html", {
        "form": form,
        "event_list": event_list,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you would write another view function, e.g. `delete_event(request, event_id)` and wire it up in `urls.py`. Inside the delete view, you would use the provided [`Model.delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#deleting-objects) function to remove the object from the database.

The choice whether to use ajax or not is mostly a matter of taste - you would need to issue a request via javascript to a similar function as I described above, which would take care of the logic.

Some additional overhead is present (when using ajax) in terms of updating the page appropriately.

The proper http verb for deletes would be `DELETE`, but since this is not usually supported out of the box, you'll use `POST`.

Comment: So something like this?

(r^events/delete/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$' 'delete_event')

Comment: But the problem with this is I don't want to be redirected to events/delete/. I want to stay on events/. Thing is, requests going to events/ are already tied up to my event view.

Comment: I might not fully understand your concern; but you can always redirect after a delete - e.g. to the page you are coming from. Say you are on `events`, you click on the link which says delete - which takes you to `events/1231/delete` (not very restful, I know ;) - and then you'll get immediately redirected back to `events`, this time with one less item in your list - wouldn't that be sufficient?